# Does Appcelerator Titanium have option to develop both iPad and Android Galaxy application?

Tags: appcelerator

I am newbie to Appcelerator Titanium, My requirement is, develop mobile application for both iPad and Android Galaxy tab. But when I start the Titanium , it asks Mobile, iPad and desktop type of apps. Can you please help me how to develop app for both iPad and tablet.

Regards
Sri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know Appcelerator supports the ability to make an iPhone / iPad combination apps (as i have done it).  I have previously worked on a prototype that was iPhone / Android in a single build / version.  You should be able to do this by going the mobile route and detecting the os, and screen dimensions. Also, there are lots of calls not supported by iPhone / Android and it's pretty tricky to make anything very complicated for both in a single project.